# ¿Es posible que una clase hija pueda utilizar atributos de su clase padre en Java?

Tags: java

En mi caso necesitaba utilizar atributos de la clase padre en el toString de la clase hija, siendo estos privados, no me fue posible hacerlo. ¿Hay alguna solución para esto?

Comment: Podrias acceder a las propiedades a traves de los getters del padre o en cambiar la visivilidad de las porpiedades a protected.

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Saludos.